# How to point latex preview to another file?

Tags: latex, preview-latex

I have two files.  A main file, say, `main.tex` which has all the boiler plate and structure, and `section.tex`, which has content.

Inside `main.tex` I have `\include{section}`.

I edit `section.tex`, because that's where the content is, and so when I use  `latex-preview-pane-mode` it gives an error, because it is trying to compile `section.tex` which has none of the necessary preamble.

Is there anyway I can point the preview pane towards `main.tex`, or some other way of achieving what I want: the ability to preview modular latex documents within Emacs?  Preferably it would be within a frame, rather than having to open an external application, and updates automatically in the way that `latex-preview-pane-mode` does.

Otherwise I will have to use a monolithic document once again and use C-c = with reftex, I suppose.

Comment: Auctex provides facilities for dealing with multifile documents: https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Multifile.html